# Trouble getting script to fire on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If someone could see what is the culprit here I would be grateful. I've tried using native JS instead of jQuery for the click function, but, the click function is not working either way. There must be something I am missing here.

HTML:

```
    <ul class="adcats">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="contactform fashion">Testing</div>
    <div class="contactform othername">Other</div>
    <div class="contactform othername2">Others</div>
```

JS code:

```
    var hideforms = jQuery('.contactform').hide();
    var buttons = jQuery('.adcats > li');
    var hideforms;
    revForm = function () {
    hideforms;
};
    buttons[0].click = function () {
        revForm;
    document.getElementsByClassName("fashion").style.display = "block";
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using native javascript, you need to use [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick) to add the click handler

```
buttons[0].onclick = function () {
}
```

using jQuery you can use [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
buttons.first().click(function(){
})
```

Also `document.getElementsByClassName("fashion").style.display = "block";` is wrong because `document.getElementsByClassName("fashion")` returns an array, not a individual dom element. So if there is only one element with class `fashion` then you need to use `document.getElementsByClassName("fashion")[0].style.display = "block";` else you need to iterate through the array and set the style

```
    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("fashion")
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i].style.display = "block";
    }
```

A working solution will be something like

```
jQuery(function () {
    var buttons = jQuery('.adcats > li');
    var forms = jQuery('.contactform').hide();

    buttons.click(function () {
        forms.hide();
        forms.filter($(this).data('target')).show()
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tuxBx/)

Comment: Great tip with pointing out the the getClass returns array even though it is indeed 1 element within. However, still not working for some reason...

Comment: @Kald you need to share your html also including the other referred elements like fashion and the contactform... also don't forget to add the script in dom ready handler

Comment: Just revised it. It's simply 3 divs that share a common class, but the common class is irrelevant to the click event.

Comment: @Kald from the looks of it what you are trying to do is http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tuxBx/2/

Comment: That's great... I haven't tried that bit of code before. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

What error do you get?
if there's nothing, but the form didn't hide, the reason must be

```
revForm = function () {
    hideforms;
};
```

it should be

```
revForm = function () {
    hideforms();
};
```

And don't forget about the call to revForm function, it should be `revForm();`

Comment: Yes I was lazy with the () although the code does run without them.

Comment: the () need to run the function. without (), the variable is only common variable (type function).
for example : 
$("a").click(hideForms); 
thats normal because you don't want to run the hideForms function, just passing it to another function.

Comment: Oh yes, definitely needed to pass an argument or function upon an event, but not to run the variable alone... but yes, proper santax is with () regardless. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".adcats > li").on('click',function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("fashion").style.display = "block";
});
```